# Winnow data.frame to principle text-containing columns?

Tags: r

I would like to identify a sensible method to detect and select the ‘principle’ text-containing data columns from my data.frames.

These columns contain open-ended survey responses, so they have heterogeneous strings comprised chiefly of letter characters.
Ideally, this method would

1. remove all factor, numeric, date and logical columns
2. remove sparsely-populated text columns
3. remove text columns with few unique elements
4. be able to deal with non-standard characters

Here is the original example of what I'd like to achieve:

**Original input data**

```
   v1   v2   v3   v4   v5 v6 v7 v8     v9 v10 v11 v12 v13   v14
1  Na   Gu   Rx   Ll bird  a  a  1 88,626   1   1   ç   a  TRUE
2  Ue   Ho   Iy <NA> bird  b  b  2 48,666   2   2   é   b FALSE
3  Vk   Lv <NA> <NA> bird  a  c  3 12,559   3   1   ë   ç  TRUE
4  Pd   Hk <NA> <NA> bird  b  d  4  3,794   4   2   õ   d FALSE
5  Ay   Nd <NA> <NA> <NA>  a  e  5 75,239   5   1   ï   é  TRUE
6  Xj <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  b  a  6 44,559   6   2   í   f FALSE
7  Zn <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  a  b  7 21,100   7   1   ð   g  TRUE
8  Mw <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  b  c  8  7,790   8   2   ø   h FALSE
9  Yx <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  a  d  9 84,470   9   1   ö   i  TRUE
10 Oj <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  b  e 10 45,724  10   2   ò   j FALSE
```

**Original desired output (flawed, see Update below)**

```
    v1   v2 v7 v12 v13
1  Na   Gu  a   c   a
2  Ue   Ho  b   e   b
3  Vk   Lv  c   e   c
4  Pd   Hk  d   o   d
5  Ay   Nd  e   i   e
6  Xj <NA>  a   i   f
7  Zn <NA>  b   d   g
8  Mw <NA>  c   o   h
9  Yx <NA>  d   o   i
10 Oj <NA>  e   o   j
```

Here is the code for the original input data:

```
# made-up data
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
  v1 = paste0(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace = T), sample(letters, 10, replace = T)),
  v2 = c(paste0(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace = T), sample(letters, 5, replace = T)), rep(NA, 5)),
  v3 = c(paste0(sample(LETTERS, 2, replace = T), sample(letters, 2, replace = T)), rep(NA, 8)),
  v4 = c(paste0(sample(LETTERS, 1, replace = T), sample(letters, 1, replace = T)), rep(NA, 9)),
  v5 = c(rep("bird", 4), rep(NA, 6)),
  v6 = factor(rep(c("a", "b"), 5)),
  v7 = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),2),
  v8 = 1:10,
  v9 = paste0(sample(1:99, 10, replace =T), ",", sample(1:999, 10, replace =T)),
  v10 = as.character(1:10),
  v11 = factor(rep(c(1, 2), 5)),
  v12 = c('ç','é','ë','õ','ï','í','ð','ø','ö','ò'),
  v13 = c('a','b', 'ç','d',' é',letters[6:10]),
  v14 = as.logical(rep(c("TRUE", "FALSE"), 5)))
```

So far I've been able to isolate the character vectors

```
df <- df[, sapply(df, is.character)]
```

And convert all the characer to Latin_ASCII, to replace non-standard letters

```
df[] <- lapply(df, stringi::stri_trans_general, "Latin-ASCII")
```

But I am trying to find a sensible/reliable solution to remove sparsely-populated (like v3 and v4), highly-repetitive (like v5), or would-be numeric data formatted as characters (like v9 and v10). What's a good approach?

**Update**

After receiving a useful answer and comment from @Matias Andina, I came to realize my original input data was flawed, because 10 rows of data were insufficient to correctly capture my goal of removing text columns with "few unique elements". So here is a second example, showing the first twenty rows to the input and desired output. Consistent with my original question described at the top of this post,the goal is to drop all the "d" columns, and keep the "k" columns. Matias deserves credit, for his answer already handles d3-d9.

**Supplementary input data**

```
 k1 k2  k3  d1  d2      d3     d4   d5  d6  d7  d8      d9
Ze  E,w h,Y c   bird   12,36    b   38  38  2   FALSE   18/03/2020
Gr  Y,y w,J d   NA     88,510   b   54  54  2   FALSE   3/04/2020
Ze  J,x w,G e   bird   26,932   b   30  30  2   FALSE   10/03/2020
Nt  V,u a,A d   bird    8,660   a   19  19  1   TRUE    28/02/2020
Bn  W,l z,O c   bird   19,684   a   3   3   1   TRUE    12/02/2020
Km  L,c h,d a   bird    8,649   b   16  16  2   FALSE   25/02/2020
Lx  N,e s,H d   NA     92,838   b   84  84  2   FALSE   3/05/2020
Vv  R,s m,b e   bird   58,793   b   40  40  2   FALSE   20/03/2020
El  A,h i,E d   bird   61,589   b   44  44  2   FALSE   24/03/2020
Az  B,b n,é c   NA     45,11    b   58  58  2   FALSE   7/04/2020
Tq  J,y w,N b   NA     81,288   b   82  82  2   FALSE   1/05/2020
Lg  Z,l h,I c   NA     17,418   b   88  88  2   FALSE   7/05/2020
Oh  F,b e,Q a   NA     28,887   a   71  71  1   TRUE    20/04/2020
Rj  I,f ç,F b   NA     59,213   a   97  97  1   TRUE    16/05/2020
Pw  X,u n,Z b   bird   51,622   b   42  42  2   FALSE   22/03/2020
Dv  A,d l,X c   bird   29,148   b   18  18  2   FALSE   27/02/2020
Hp  C,o w,Z d   bird   78,737   b   24  24  2   FALSE   4/03/2020
Br  D,i b,a e   NA     35,231   a   65  65  1   TRUE    14/04/2020
Re  X,g b,O b   NA     18,244   b   92  92  2   FALSE   11/05/2020
```

**Corrected desired output**

```
k1  k2  k3  
Ze  E,w h,Y 
Gr  Y,y w,J 
Ze  J,x w,G 
Nt  V,u a,A 
Bn  W,l z,O 
Km  L,c h,d 
Lx  N,e s,H 
Vv  R,s m,b 
El  A,h i,E 
Az  B,b n,é 
Tq  J,y w,N 
Lg  Z,l h,I 
Oh  F,b e,Q 
Rj  I,f ç,F 
Pw  X,u n,Z 
Dv  A,d l,X 
Hp  C,o w,Z 
Br  D,i b,a 
Re  X,g b,O
```

Here is the code for the supplementary input data:

```
set.seed(8)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F, 
  k1 = paste0(sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T), sample(letters, 100, replace = T)),
  k2 = paste0(sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T), ",", sample(letters, 100, replace = T)),
  k3 = paste0(sample(c('a','b', 'ç','d',' é',letters), 100, replace = T), ",",
    sample(c('a','b', 'ç','d',' é', LETTERS), 100, replace = T)),
  d1 = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),20),
  d2 = c(rep("bird", 51), rep(NA, 49)),
  d3 = paste0(sample(1:99, 100, replace =T), ",", sample(1:999, 100, replace =T)),
  d4 = factor(rep(c("a", "b"), 50)),
  d5 = 1:100,
  d6 = as.character(1:100),
  d7 = factor(rep(c(1, 2), 10)),
  d8 = as.logical(rep(c("TRUE", "FALSE"), 50)),
  d9 = seq(from = as.Date("2020-02-10"), to = as.Date("2020-02-10") + 99, by = 'day'))

df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might explode in your real data but I think it can be tinkered with.

```
library(tidyverse)
step_one <- df %>% 
  # change the commas for dots (may explode if you actually have commas)
  mutate_if(.predicate = function(x) is.character(x),
            .funs = function(x) stringr::str_replace_all(x, ",", ".")) %>%
  select_if(.predicate =  function(x) is.character(x) && is.na(as.numeric(x)) == TRUE && is.logical(x) == FALSE) %>% 
  mutate_all(.funs = function(x) stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "Latin-ASCII"))


step_one %>%
  summarise_each(funs = function(x) sum(is.na(x))) %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  mutate(variable = as.character(variable),
         total_cases = nrow(df),
         frac = value/total_cases,
# --->>> arbitrary 0.5 threshold <<<<----
         sparse = ifelse(frac>0.5, "remove", "keep")) %>%
  filter(sparse == "keep") %>%
  pull(variable) -> variables_to_keep

df %>% select(variables_to_keep)
```

Which produces

```
   v1   v2 v7 v12 v13
1  Bq   Um  a   ç   a
2  Tb   Aq  b   é   b
3  Wv   Cf  c   ë   ç
4  Mf   Sl  d   õ   d
5  Ou   Ah  e   ï   é
6  Ag <NA>  a   í   f
7  Rl <NA>  b   ð   g
8  Mw <NA>  c   ø   h
9  Kj <NA>  d   ö   i
10 Bd <NA>  e   ò   j
```

or

```
step_one %>% select(variables_to_keep)
   v1   v2 v7 v12 v13
1  Bq   Um  a   c   a
2  Tb   Aq  b   e   b
3  Wv   Cf  c   e   c
4  Mf   Sl  d   o   d
5  Ou   Ah  e   i   e
6  Ag <NA>  a   i   f
7  Rl <NA>  b   d   g
8  Mw <NA>  c   o   h
9  Kj <NA>  d   o   i
10 Bd <NA>  e   o   j
```

### UPDATE

I think this should get you closer to where you want to go...

```
remove_high_repetition_variables <- function(df){
  tallies <- df %>%
    purrr::map(function(tt) as.data.frame(table(tt))) %>%
    purrr::map(function(tt) mutate(tt,
                                  unique_values = length(tt),
                                  total = sum(Freq),
                                  highly_rep = total/unique_values,
                                  representation = Freq/total,
   # Your thresholds here
   # 100-element vector had only 20 unique values or less
                                  flag = ifelse(highly_rep > 100/20, "remove", "keep"))) %>%
  purrr::map(function (tt) any(pull(tt, flag) == "remove"))

 if (any(tallies == TRUE)){
   return(names(tallies[tallies == FALSE]))  
 } else {
   return(names(tallies))
 }

}
```

The usage is meant to be with `dplyr::select`

```
remove_high_repetition_variables(step_two)
[1] "k1" "k2" "k3"
remove_high_repetition_variables(mtcars)
[1] "mpg"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec"
```

In such a way that you can get what you want

```
step_two %>% select(remove_high_repetition_variables(.)
```

Comment: Note that "highly-repetitive (like v5)" is also quite empty...I didn't look for repeated variables, this might fail in your real dataset

Comment: Still, your answer helps. When time permits, I am going to post a more robust sample data, and continue tinkering.

Comment: I have updated my question. We could roll-back if the answer-er prefers?

Comment: what are the criteria for removing d1 and d2 ? Will `c("Bird","Bird","Bird","Bird", NA, NA, NA, "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Bird")` count ?

Comment: There is a threshold issue for them, so it's hard to give a precise explanation. But I'd say roughly that if a 100-element vector had only 20 unique values or less, then those values are more likely "labels" than actual open-ended text. So, by this criterion, if your example were repeated to 100 cases with the same proportion, it would also be dropped